# Swiper API - onSetTranslate callback stopped running

Tags: javascript, jquery, swiper.js, idangero

I'm using the Swiper API to do a cool carousel at beginning of my project,  [Swiper Sample](http://idangero.us/swiper/#.WQpuptJ96Uk)

In the project I'm working on, I need to do an animation with some images at the same time I drag the swipe, it is working really great with these setting:

```
var bgAnim = function () {
    var opacity = (100 + (swiper.translate / 8)) / 100,
        move = swiper.translate / 4,
        tDur = $('.swiper-wrapper').css('transition-duration').slice(0, -1) * 1000; // ## problem to run AUTOPLAY
    if (move > 0) { move = 0 }
    if (move < -200) { move = -200 }
    if (opacity > 1) { opacity = 1 }
    if (opacity < 0) { opacity = 0; tDur = tDur / 2 }

    $('#girl-bg').animate({     // ## problem to run AUTOPLAY
        'left': move,
        'opacity': opacity
    }, tDur);

    $('#logo-bg').animate({     // ## problem to run AUTOPLAY
        'opacity': opacity
    }, tDur);
}

var swiper = new Swiper('.vision', {
    //autoplay: 500,
    autoplayDisableOnInteraction: false,
    slidesPerView: 3,
    spaceBetween: 24,
    freeMode: true,
    slidesOffsetAfter: 1000,
    onSetTranslate: bgAnim
});
```

The problem is, when I use `autoplay` it conflicts with the two lines I marked above code snippet, if I take the `"animate"` and `$('.swiper-wrapper').css('transition-duration')` off it works well, but I need both to animate the background images...

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, I did an AutoPlay with some methods and callbacks as you can see below and it worked perfectly. (:

```
    var swiperAutoplay = function () {
            swiper.setWrapperTranslate(swiper.getWrapperTranslate() - 1);
            swiper.update(true);
            var autoTime = setTimeout(swiperAutoplay, 3);
            $(homeSwiper).children().click(function () {
                clearTimeout(autoTime);
            });
   };

    setTimeout(swiperAutoplay, 5000);
```